# Why after refresh the page some jQuery script is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

After refresh the page jquery script is not working. I used both $(document).ready(); and $(window).load(); function. This code is used for fit the image.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="coverPicContainer">
    <img class="cover" src="<?php echo base_url()?>core/uploads/company/<?php echo $cover_image?>" alt="cover"/>
</div>`
```

CSS Code

```
#coverPicContainer {
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left:-15px;
    height: 410px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
#coverPicContainer img.wide {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#coverPicContainer img.tall {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and jQuery Code

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#coverPicContainer').find('img').each(function() {
        var imgClass = (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
        $(this).addClass(imgClass);
    });
});
```

When i refresh the page some time its working and some time its not working.
Thank you for your great  help.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Always works here(*run, refresh, update*):
http://jsfiddle.net/L4m9dfby/1/

**Note:** Script is executed on windows load.

A possible solution to your particular problem would be to put `window.load function` outside of your `document ready`.